# Unpack 2d list of tuples

Tags: python, list, tuples

I am trying to unpack a 2D list of tuples. Everything I have tried so far is not giving me the results

This is what I am trying to achieve:

```
Input:  [[(-8, -8), (2, 0)], [(0, 2), (-1, -1)]]    

Output = [[-8, 2], [0, -1]], [[-8, 0], [2, -1]]
```

I have tried zip like this but it does not work.

```
a,b = zip(*matrixRow)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to apply `zip` twice to perform 2 transpositions:

```
inlist = [[(-8, -8), (2, 0)], [(0, 2), (-1, -1)]]

print(list(zip(*(zip(*x) for x in inlist))))
```

result:

```
[((-8, 2), (0, -1)), ((-8, 0), (2, -1))]
```

this gives `tuples` inside because `zip` creates them. To get lists, it's a little more complicated because you have to convert to `list` at 2 levels:

```
print([[list(z) for z in y] for y in zip(*(zip(*x) for x in inlist))])
```

prints:

```
[[[-8, 2], [0, -1]], [[-8, 0], [2, -1]]]
```